# RxJava Take operator is not working

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

**What I want to achieve:** I am loading data from some web service in recyclerView. I want to load first 10 data and display it in recyclerView. When User scrolls, call web service for another 10 data to display it.

**What I have done:** For above aim, I'm using **.take** operator of RxJava. But It seems not working for me or else I'm doing some mistake.

**What issue I'm having:** I'm getting all the data instead of first 5 data. There might be something that I'm missing it.

My code is like below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        setupProgressDialog();

        ApiEndPoints apiEndPoints = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiEndPoints.class);

        mProgressDialog.show();

        apiEndPoints.fetchAllUsers()
                .take(5)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //Background Thread
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //UI Thread
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<Pojo>>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onNext(List<Pojo> pojoList) {

                                   recyclerView.setAdapter(new RVAdapter(pojoList));

                                   Log.e(TAG, "List Size: " + pojoList.size());
                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onError(Throwable e) {

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onComplete() {
                                   mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                               }
                           }
                );
    }

    private void setupProgressDialog() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading . . . ");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
}
```

Ask me if anything required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use take operator, It will emit first 5 items and than onCompleted function will trigger. So you need re observable source.

I found example application on [github](https://gist.github.com/dustin-graham/52eaaab1cb3a41aba444) which is using rxjava for load more operation.

Comment: What do you mean by **re observable**? Should I need to observe again in **onComplete** method? If possible can you give example code?@gokhan

Comment: @MaulikDodia  If you use take operator with 5, data stream will close ta  emitting after emitted 5 item. [link](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html)

Comment: It did not. That is the main problem. I'm unable to find the problem.@gokhan

Answer (score 0):

You receive a list, which is considered as an object. You need to iterate them, take first 5 and then get them back as a list:

```
apiEndPoints.fetchAllUsers()
            // iterate users
            .concatMap(new Func1<List<Pojo>, Observable<Pojo>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Pojo> call(List<Pojo> pojos) {
                    return Observable.from(pojos);
                }
            })
            // take 5 from iteration
            .take(5)
            // put all 5 users back to a list
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //Background Thread
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //UI Thread
```

If you had an array (`Pojos[] users`) `take()` operator should work without iteration.

Comment: It giving me error like `Cannot resolve symbol Func1` and `Cannot resolve symbol from(java.util.List<package.name.Pojo>)`. Any idea@FlorescuCătălin

Comment: It depends by RxJava version, don't just paste it. Is just an example. @MaulikDodia

Comment: Let me check it. Thanks fro your response.@FlorescuCătălin